# jquery ajax data container

Tags: javascript, jquery, containers

I'm developing a client-side application that will load quite a lot of data via ajax and store it somewhere in javascript models. In short, my application has following elements:

- AJAX calls: loading user list, loading financial data (user incomes and outcomes, loading chart data based on incomes/outcomes)
- the list of users is loaded during initial page load (and it doesn't change)
- financial data can be retrieved for chosen users for a given time period
- there is a dialog with user checkbox list - after the dialog is submitted, financial data will be retrieved (via ajax) for those users

So there would be some ajax calls only once per entire page load and some ajax calls that would be called each time any filters are changed.

I've found out that jquery provides a `.data()` function that binds data to specific DOM objects. But, as you can see, I don't need to bind my data to a specific DOM object, but just to manage it globally. Is there any recommended approach, what would you suggest?

Comment: what's wrong with a global variable object?

Comment: @RezaOwliaei there's nothing wrong. I just hate to reinvent the wheel - that's why I ask for hints, good approaches, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For global data you can consider a global javascript object that contains the values.  For instance, declare globalData:

```
var globalData = {users : /*Put User List Here*/ };
```

Then just assign values to the global data object as it is retrieved.

```
$.ajax(success:function(data){
    globalData.transactions = data;
});
```

You could assign data constrained to specific UI elements using the .data() function.  For instance if you have a section of the page that displays account lists you use the .data() function, such as this ajax request for an account list.

```
$.ajax(success:function(data){
    $("#accountList").data(data);
});
```

Comment: Is $('body').data() also considerable?